# Getting Ethernet error in Android

Tags: android, logcat, ethernet

I am running Android 5.1.1 on a OTT Box. WiFi works fine but when I turn off WiFi and plug in my Ethernet cable I get no internet connection. I ran a log cat and found some issues arising. It looks as though Ethernet tries to initiate but can't. If anyone can help me figure this out or point me in the right direction it would help a lot.

```
1. Calling a method in the system process without a qualified user: android.app.ContextImpl.sendBroadcast:1327 android.content.ContextWrapper.sendBroadcast:377 com.droidlogic.PPPoE.MyPppoeService.updatInterfaceState:79 com.droidlogic.PPPoE.MyPppoeService.access$200:25 com.droidlogic.PPPoE.MyPppoeService$InterfaceObserver.interfaceLinkStateChanged:86

2. updateInterface: eth0 link up

3. setInterfaceCanUp eth0

4. Setting iface cfg

5. Trying to bring up eth0

6. startNetwork()

7. dhcpThread(+eth0): mNetworkInfo=[type: Ethernet[], state: DISCONNECTED/DISCONNECTED, reason: (unspecified), extra: c4 2F:ac:49:96:12, roaming: false, failover: false, isAvailable: true, isConnectedToProvisioningNetwork: false]

8. version 5.5.6 starting

9. eth0: broadcasting for a lease

10. timed out

11. dhcp_do_request failed: eth0 (new)

12. DHCP request error:Timed out waiting for DHCP to finish

13. stopNetwork()

14. No NetworkAgent, try to stop DHCP
```